# Executable Python package with web interface - is it possible?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and I am trying to built a bot. The bot is basically a console app that scrap some data. I would like to distribute this bot as a package for Desktop (at least windows) and also need a web-version of the same.

My questions are :

1. Is it possible to have a web based UI for this bot so that same UI can be used for Desktop and Online versions. The main function of UI is to turn on/off the bot.
2. Is it possible to package everything into .exe and .dlls so that it work on Windows OS that don't have python installed. When the user open the exe file the web-UI open in an inbuilt browser (eg: chromium) from where he can turn off/on the robot. The robot should run as a background process when turned on through the UI

So basically what I want is to distribute a downloadable version of the bot and also run a hosted service. And I need same interface for both desktop and online versions.

Is this possible? How can I get it done?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I don't know if you really want to use python, but if you don't, you could use at Adober AIR and JavaScript. It's a runtime environment which uses web technologies so making the UI wouldn't require to rewrite for both Web and Desktop. I would also discourage from using Python at all but that is a different topic (tips: Reference counting, and Performance).

Comment: well, I have already made it in python. Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use py2exe or [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) to package and distribute your application for Windows desktop users. As for the interface, there's nothing preventing you from writing a web application where running the executable would start a web server and open the application in the user's default browser, or you could simply resort to parsing command line arguments for desktop users.

If you'd like to use web documents as your primary interface, a simple solution might be just using the user's default web browser to access your application, which is configured in the Windows registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\http\shell\open\command\(Default)`. Another solution might be to redistribute the browser together with your application, but legally your mileage may vary here because of trademark policies, even for open source projects.

The best approach, where you'd have a greater degree of freedom to develop your application-specific user experiences, would be to create a GUI application with a suitable Python GUI toolkit and embed a layout engine, such as Gecko, Chromium or Webkit, into the the UI.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to embed a browser along with the executable so that the web app loads in that one instead of opening in users browser. Also how can a button on the web UI turn of and turn on the robot? I can't figure out how to do it for both desktop and web version.

Comment: Haha, that's close to my suggestion, just mentioning :-). About your question it depends on what widget toolkit / gui library you are using, but it's probably possible in most of them. For sure in QT, which, AFAIK has Python binding.

Comment: I suggest using cxFreeze for packaging Python into an executable; it's equal or superior to py2exe in every way I'm aware of, and can produce standalone executables for MacOS or indeed Linux systems as well.

Comment: Thanks @Schilcote, I've included cx_Freeze in the answer